# You have an error in your SQL syntax,check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Tags: mysql

$w ='SELECT Sl_no,name,branch,phone,email_id,rating,group  FROM admin_user WHERE group = branchadmin ' ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group` is a reserved word due to the `GROUP BY` possibilities.

Surround `group` with back-quotes.

Also you forgot to put quotes around the `branchadmin` string.

```
$w ='SELECT Sl_no,name,branch,phone,email_id,rating,`group` FROM admin_user WHERE `group` = "branchadmin" ' ;
```

Comment: Note that you have 2 uses of `group` and each of them has to be surrounded by back-quotes.

Comment: Can you mark as answer or vote up or both if it helped?

Answer (score 0):

"group" is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).  To use it as an identifier it needs to be escaped with back-ticks:

```
SELECT `group` FROM Table WHERE `group` = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of field group. GROUP is a word reserved by mysql